# Размер md5 хэша

Tags: php, md5

Насколько известно (из той же Википедии) MD5 хеш содержит 128 бит (16 байт). Но почему-то, когда я используя php функцию md5('test') и получаю хэш **098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6**, то он весит 32 байта (что соответственно рано 256 битам). Кодировки UTF-8, ANSI.

Скажите, пожалуйста, кто знает, что я упускаю из вида?

Comment: Может быть все зависит от кодировки?

Comment: Да, именно. Если ты хранишь хэш как 16ричное число, то конечно же он будет занимать 128 бит. А так, ты хранишь как строку

Comment: тогда, было бы интересно в какой кодировке было получено 128 бит. Я перепробовал UTF-8 (и UTF8+BOM), ANSI, UNICODE.Вроде они самые популярные.

Comment: Ну посчитай сам. 32 символа. 128 бит. 4 бита на каждый символ. 2^4=16 вариантов символов. Соответственно это 32значное 16ричное число.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Сам по себе алгоритм MD5 возвращает 128-битное число. Но функция `md5` в PHP возвращает не само число, а его строковое представление. В нём каждый из 16 байтов числа представлен двузначным шестнадцатеричным числом от 00 до ff. Отсюда строка из 32 символов.

Comment: Все спасибо дошло. Просто документацию (php) мне надо было внимательно прочесть. Если необязательный аргумент raw_output имеет значение TRUE, то возвращается бинарная строка из 16 символов.

Comment: Ммм да. Я вроде то же самое сказал. Может непонятно изъяснился?

Comment: Вы не то же самое сказали. Вы сделали упор на кодировку, а проблема - в представлении чисел. В памяти хэш занимает 128 бит (16 байт), но его _удобочитаемое представление_ каждый байт числа представляет двумя символами (байтами). Отсюда 32 байта (256 бит), и Юникод тут не при чём. В чистом (неудобочитаемом) виде хэш выглядел бы так: `" kÍF!ÓsÊÞN&'´ö"` (без кавычек).

Comment: Вот код на JS, преобразующий удобочитаемый хэш в его реальное представление в памяти:

    var str = '098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6';
    str.match(/.{2}/g).map(function(s) { return String.fromCharCode(parseInt('0x' + s)); }).join('');

Comment: На самом деле md5-хэш это число, но оно получается настолько большим, что его представляют в виде строки, описывающих байты, из которых оно состоит. В `int` или `long` хэш не влезает, а в `float` появляется погрешность представления.

Comment: Прочитайте, пожалуйста, первый комментарий к моему ответу. Я это и имел в виду, MD5 хранится в виде строки, поэтому и занимает гораздо больше места. Если бы он и хранился в виде числа, то и занимал бы место в 128 бит

Comment: Нет, нет и нет. В виде _неудобочитаемой строки_ хэш состоит из 16 символов (байт). Но, ещё раз повторюсь, функция md5 возвращает _удобочитаемую строку_, в которой каждый символ исходной строки заменяется на два. Никакого отношения к кодировке это явление не имеет. Возможно, именно это в и имели ввиду, но донести это до ТС'а (да и до меня тоже) вы не смогли.